# Are there any continuous time-limited Linear and Time-Invariant (LIT) functions with unbounded derivative?

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis, physics, signal-processing, finite-duration

**Are there any continuous time-limited Linear and Time-Invariant (LIT) functions with unbounded derivative?**

Let think about a continuous and time-limited function $q(t)$ that is representing a classical mechanics phenomena, which can be represented as the output of a LIT system with impulse response $h(t)$.

Now, I want to know which is the maximum rate of change that can possible achieve the function $q(t)$, so as a worst case I test this system against a discontinuous jump-alike change by using as input the unitary standard step function $\theta(t)$, so:
$$q(t) = h(t)\circledast\theta(t)$$
related through the convolution operator as every LIT system.

Now, **I believe** that since $q(t)$ is continuous and time limited, and $\theta(t)$ is not a compacted-supported function, the only alternative to made $q(t)$ as it is, is by an $h(t)$ function that is also continuous and time-limited (**please correct me if I am wrong, this is the most important assumption on the presented line-of-thought**).

With this, since $q(t)$ and $h(t)$ are both continuous and compact-supported (because they are both time-limited), they are also bounded functions $\sup_t |q(t)| < \infty$ and $\sup_t |h(t)| < \infty$. And also remember, that since $q(t)$ and $h(t)$ are both time-limited, it implies that both are also of **unlimited bandwidth** (i.e., they aren´t band-limited functions).

Now, following the exercise n° 4.49 of the book "Signals and Systems, 2nd Edition" (Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, with S. Hamid) [[1]](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Oppenheim-Signals-and-Systems-2nd-Edition/PGM10192.html), and the following properties:

1. $\frac{d}{dt}\Big(x(t) \circledast y(t) \Big) = \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \circledast y(t) = x(t) \circledast \frac{dy(t)}{dt}$ as is shown on  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Algebraic_properties): Algebraic Properties --> Relation with differentitation.
2. The derivative of the unitary step function is the Dirac's delta function $\theta'(t) = \delta(t)$, as is shown on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).
3. and $f(t) = f(t) \circledast \delta(t)$ as is shown on  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Algebraic_properties): Algebraic Properties --> Multiplicative identity.

So, I will have that $$q'(t) = h(t) \circledast \theta'(t) = h(t) \circledast \delta(t) = h(t)$$
and since $|h(t)|< \infty$ is bounded if my first assumptions are right, I will have that the maximum rate of change of
$$\sup_t |q'(t)| = sup_t |h(t)| < \infty$$
so **even they are functions of unlimited bandwidth they will ALWAYS have a bounded derivative**:

**A) Does this means that every continuous and time-limited LIT functions have a bounded maximum rate of change $\sup_t |q'(t)|< \infty$?**

By construction, I already know that if impulse response $h(t)$ is continuous and time-limited then the maximum rate of change of $q(t)$ will be bounded, if the analysis against the unitary step $\theta(t)$ is general enough (**Is that so?**).

But in the other way, if $q(t)$ is continuous and time-limited, I feel that it could not be necessarily implying that $h(t)$ is also continuous and time-limited, since $q(t) = h(t) \circledast \theta(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t h(t)\,dt$ and I am not sure **if the integral of a discontinuous function could lead to a continuous function, hope you can explain this too**.

---

**Added later:**

I have just notice that any function can be described as:
$$q(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t q'(t)\,dt = q'(t)\circledast \theta(t)$$
so requiring that the impulse response function $h(t) \equiv q'(t)$ to be continuous and time-limited is already requiring that $|q'(t)|<\infty$ been bounded.

---

Other interesting facts from exercise 4.49:

Since from the properties of the Laplace Transform of $q(t)$ given by $Q(s)$, I will have that:
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} q(t) = q(\infty) = \lim_{s \to 0} s\,Q(s) = \lim_{s \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dq(t)}{dt}e^{-st}dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty q'(t)\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t)\,dt$$

so I can model the "minimum possible response time to the step function" $\Delta t_{\min}$ as:
$$ \sup_t |q'(t)| = \Bigg| \frac{q(\infty)}{\Delta t_{min}}\Bigg| \Rightarrow \Delta t_{min} = \frac{|q(\infty)|}{\sup_t|q'(t)|} = \frac{|\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t)\,dt|}{\sup_t |h(t)|} $$

so I could define an "effective Bandwidth" for this system response to the step function using as maximum frequency the quantity $f_{max} = 1/ \Delta t_{min}$:
$$B_W = 2 f_{max} = \frac{2}{\Delta t_{min}} = \frac{2\sup_t |h(t)|}{|\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(t)\,dt|}$$
with Uncertainty relation $$ B_W \cdot \Delta t_{min} > 2$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized later that the questions is ill-posed, but since other person bookmarked it, before deleting it I will give what know I think is the answer.

I have found the following paper named "[Finite time differential equations](https://www.sci-hub.se/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832)" by V. T. Haimo (1985), where continuous time differential equations with finite-duration solutions are studied, an it is stated the following:

*"One notices immediately that finite time differential equations cannot be Lipschitz at the origin. As all solutions reach zero in finite time, there is non-uniqueness of solutions through zero in backwards time. This, of course, violates the uniqueness condition for solutions of Lipschitz differential equations."*

Since, linear differential equations have solutions that are unique, and finite-duration solutions aren´t, finite-duration phenomena models must be non-linear to show the required behavior (non meaning this, that every non-linear dynamic system support finite-duration solutions).

The paper also show which conditions must fulfill the non-linear differential equation to support finite-duration solutions, at least for first and second order scalar ODEs.

So, if the paper is right (I can't prove or disprove it), no LTI system could have finite-duration solutions, since they are described through linear differential equations, and with this, the question can´t have an answer since is asking for finite-duration LIT system, which can´t exists (or the system is linear, or is of finite-duration, can´t be both).